# kdb/q update multiple different values in one column for different key in keyed table

Tags: kdb, q-lang

I have a table, which is :

```
t:([alpha:`a`b`c`d`e`f];beta:10 20 30 40 50 60)
```

I also have two variable:

```
chgkey:`b`c
chgvalue:2000 -1000
```

I want to do something like:

```
t:update beta:2000 from t where alpha=`b;
t:update beta:-1000 from t where alpha=`c;
```

My question is how to combine these two lines of code. Because I am working on a table which is far bigger than this simple example and it will take me a lot of rows of codes to do all the updates, which is too long.

It would be nice something like

```
t[chgkey]`beta:chgvalue;
```

Answer (score 3):

> It would be nice something like t[chgkey]`beta:chgvalue

A working solution is only slightly more complicated:

```
t[([]alpha:chgkey);`beta]:chgvalue
```

Answer (score 2):

I would try to use the next query. But note that it may be slow in case if your `dict` is really huge

```
dict: `b`c ! 1000 2000;
t: update beta: ?[alpha in key dict; dict alpha;beta] from t;
```

In case if table `t` is global it can be updated with functional update:

```
{![`t;enlist (=;`alpha;enlist x);0b; enlist[`beta]!enlist y];}'[`b`c; 1000 2000]
```

Comment: Yes, dictionary solution is nice. Can also just use fill rather than checking the keys: update beta:beta^dict alpha from t

Comment: Thanks a lot terrylynch and Dovzhenko, it's really helpful.